# MySQL how to use GROUP BY and BETWEEN?

Tags: mysql, group-by, between

I have a table in mysql which contain column inv_no, inv_date and total_amt. How can I return a table like below:-

```
--------------------------------------------
| Hourly     | Transaction_Qty | Total_Amt |
--------------------------------------------
|00:00-00:59 |x                |y          |
|01:00-01:59 |x                |y          |
|02:00-02:59 |x                |y          |
|03:00-03:59 |x                |y          |
|and so on......
```

Here is my code:

```
Dim query As String = "
SELECT COUNT(inv_no) AS TotalTransactionQty, SUM(total_amt) AS TotalAmount
FROM sales
GROUP BY DATE(inv_date)"
```

Above code can only seperate by date, How can I use group by and between to seperate my table to 24 rows?

Comment: Is inv_date a date field?

Comment: @P.Salmon yes, it is a timestamp

Comment: how is this related with between?

Comment: @LelioFaieta between 00:00 to 00:59?

Comment: I think this is more suited to the psychic forum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT Hour(inv_date) As HourOfDay 
     , COUNT(inv_no) AS TotalTransactionQty
     , SUM(total_amt) AS TotalAmount 
  FROM sales 
 GROUP 
    BY Hour(inv_date)
```